# how to consume a woo commerce webhook using webApi

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, rest

I'm new to woo Commerce. I have managed to set this up in wordpress and I can add products, create orders etc. I've added a webhook against order creation. The endpoint that I have specified is an endpoint written as a C# service:

```
public class WooController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/woo/createOrder")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateOrder(object order)
        {
            var tt = order;
        }
```

I know my endpoint is all good as I can get to it using swagger. However, when creating the webhook in woo commerce, when I save the webhook I immediately receive a 204 error. I'm guessing it's trying to 'poke' the endpoint to ensure it exists. I can only think that declaring the endpoint with 'object' isn't correct. I cant finid anything that shows what my signature should be for this endpoint. Can anyone out there give an example.

Comment: Why do you say 204 is an error? It's a valid no content response, which looks good, given that your EP returns void.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh In that case Maybe I'm not attaching my debugger correctly. I'm trying to see what is in my order object coming over, so From visual studio I attempt to attach to the browser, but my Method doesn't get hit so maybe my question should be how do I attach the debugger to woo

Comment: To check if the debugger is attached, you can set a breakpoint at the first line in `Main`.

Comment: @vernou I set a breakpoint on my var tt which should get hit if I'm attached to the correct process. It never get's hit just attaching to the browser page running woo

Comment: The trick is to determinate if the debugger isn't attached or the instruction isn't reached.

Comment: Do you hit your breakpoint from swagger? Can it be that swagger reaches out to your local instance based on swagger config (localhost/api...), whereas the webhook calls something like mysite.com/api, where some version of your app is running and returning a 204?

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh Strangely, it doesn't break using swagger, but it does run as I get correct responses.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh I've managed to get to my brakpoint via swagger now, but it still doesn't hit from my webhook

Comment: what host is defined in the swagger file and what is the url of the web hook? are you hitting the same application?

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh Not sure what happened, I just cleaned and rebuild my service and bang......suddenly attaching to the page that woo is running in caused my breakpoint to be hit. I can see all my data. Thanks for your patients with me.